# Where is the AirPlay menu bar app?

Tags: airplay

Apple hardware requirements state that AirPlay is not supported on my 2010 Macbook pro.

However, I can use AirPlay to stream music/movies from iTunes to my Apple TV (4th gen), as well as YouTube videos on Safari.

So why can't I get a menu bar app? AirPlay clearly is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirPlay is supported, extending or mirroring your Mac's desktop over AirPlay is *not* supported. As far as I know, the only way to stream from the menu bar is to stream system audio by Option-clicking the sound/volume icon. i think video streaming is still per-app if you can't do AirPlay desktop mirroring/extending.